# Ant4Eclipse - exclude some source folder on buildJdtProject task

Tags: java, ant, compilation, ant4eclipse

I would like to know if it's possible with Ant4Eclipse to exclude some folders, or files from compilation with the buildJdtProject task.

```
<buildJdtProject workspaceId="myWorkspace" projectName="@{projectName}" targetLevel="1.6" />
```

Best regards,

Florent

Comment: Anyone can help me with this subject ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the workspace definition and exclude your folder there.

```
<dirset dir="${eclipse.workspace.dir}" id="workspacedirset">
    <!-- exclude your directory-->
    <exclude name="EXCLUDEME"/>
    <!-- include all others -->
    <include name="**"/>
</dirset>
<ant4eclipse:workspaceDefinition id="myworkspace">
    <dirset refid="worspacedirset"/>
</ant4eclipse:workspaceDefinition>
```